# Expected run of colored cards

Tags: probability

I came across the following question:

There are $26$ black(B) and $26$ red(R) cards in a standard deck. A run is number of blocks of consecutive cards of the same color. For example, a sequence RRRRBBBRBRB of only $11$ cards has $6$ runs; namely, RRRR, BBB, R, B, R, B. Find the expected number of runs in a shuffled deck of cards.

One way to approach the problem uses the concept of Linearity of Expectations, wherein they argue that the probability of getting a card of a different color in the first 2 runs (Red-Blue or Blue-red in the first draws) is $(26/52)\times(26/51)\times 2$ and this will be the case for all the runs. Like so, we arrive at the answer of $27$. (A more general answer of $2\times n + 1$, where $2\times n$ is the total number of cards in the deck)

However, I find it difficult to understand why this particular probability of getting $2$ different colored cards in adjacent runs is always the same throughout the runs.

Comment: I cannot make sense of the sentence "The probability of getting a card of a different color in the first 2 runs is ..." Do you have any guess as to what this is supposed to mean?

Comment: He means that the first two cards are specifically either Red-Blue or Blue-Red.

Comment: See [Linearity of Expectation](https://brilliant.org/wiki/linearity-of-expectation/),
which includes a proof that the formula applies even when the events are not 
independent of each other.

Comment: I think you should simply include the original answer given to you, because your post is quite difficult to comprehend.

Answer (score 1):

Let $n=26$.

Define the indicator random variable $I_k$ of the event "the cards $k$ and $k+1$ are of different color". (For $k=1, \dots, 2n-1$.) Now the number of runs is equal to $1+\sum_{k=1}^{2n-1}I_k$ because you count the first run and then there will be an additional run in every point that two adjacent cards differ.

Clearly for each $k$

$$\mathbb{E}[I_k] = \mathbb{P}(k \text{'th card is different color to the } k+1) = \frac{n}{2n-1}$$

since what ever is the color of the $k$'th card, there are $n$ cards of the opposite color versus $n-1$ cards of the same color ($2n-1$ remaining cards in total). And a random permutation is as likely to put any of the remaining cards in the $k+1$'st place.

Now using linearity we get the answer

$$1 + \sum_{k=1}^{2n-1} \frac{n}{2n-1}
= 1 + n.
$$